# Passed parameter form to cycle a bash variable name to c/c++ back to bash

Tags: c, linux, string, bash

to demonstrate the problem i better preresented it in code quoted.c

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *args [] = {"/bin/bash", "-p", "./print.sh", argv[1], NULL};
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

where print.sh is just

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=Zerin
echo ${1}
```

using the command line to run compiled code as follows

```
./quoted '"$NAME"'
```

this just prints $NAME, i need it to print the value.

**Edited**

the guideline is that the script is fixed, i need to hack it! even to hack the code, i can only change the parameters!

the followings were tested:

```
./quoted '"$NAME"'
./quoted "'$NAME'"
./quoted '\"$NAME\"'
./quoted '\"\$NAME\"'
./quoted "\$NAME"
```

didn't help!

Comment: try `./quoted NAME`

Comment: NO, prints NAME,  in bash you need to prepend the name with dollar sign to print it's value

Comment: you could use `echo ${!1}` and `./quoted NAME`

Comment: @MarcoLucidi your solution works fine, if i changed the script, thanks

Comment: You *must* change the script. As written, there is no way the script will interpret the expansion of `$1` as anything other than literal text. (If it did what you want, that would be a critical security flaw.)

Comment: exactly, I'm sure it's unsecure, there is a hack, i read it.

Comment: See what happens when you run `./quoted '*'`.  Whatever you pass to `./quoted` as a parameter gets eventually expanded as a parameter to echo according to basic [Bash expansion rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions); you cannot trick this phase yet.  However, the following phases are word splitting, filename expansion, and quote removal, and you can attack those.  For example, first run `touch $'_\rTricked!'` and then `./quoted '_*'`.